# .Net AutoCAD Mechanical OperateTransaction.Commit doesn't work

Tags: .net, autocad

I create a new Layer and want user select an object which will belong the new Layer

```cs
Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;

 using (Transaction OperateTransaction = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    using (LayerTable LayerList = OperateTransaction.GetObject(acCurDb.LayerTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as LayerTable)
    {
        LayerTableRecord NewLayer = new LayerTableRecord();
        NewLayer.Color = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Colors.Color.FromColor(Color.FromArgb(RandomNum.Next(255), RandomNum.Next(255), RandomNum.Next(255)));
        NewLayer.Name = NewLayerName;

        OperateTransaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(NewLayer, true);
    }

    OperateTransaction.Commit();
}


PromptSelectionResult acSSPrompt = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.GetSelection();

 if (acSSPrompt.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
 {
     //... Assign object to new layer
 }
```

In AutoCAD 2013 & AutoCAD 2013 it work, when user select object he can see the new layer in AutoCAD, but in AutoCAD Mechanical 2016 it doesn't work, unless my .Net program is close.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the layer to the layer Table:

```
using (LayerTable LayerList = OperateTransaction.GetObject(acCurDb.LayerTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as LayerTable)
{
    LayerTableRecord NewLayer = new LayerTableRecord();
    NewLayer.Color = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Colors.Color.FromColor(Color.FromArgb(RandomNum.Next(255), RandomNum.Next(255), RandomNum.Next(255)));
    NewLayer.Name = NewLayerName;

    //add this
    LayerList.Add(NewLayer)

    OperateTransaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(NewLayer, true);
}
```